# Trying to get jquery code to work in external file without conflicting with other jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict

When I put this simple code in it's own file i get some jquery conflicts with another code.

```
jQuery(function ($){

        $(".tabContents").hide();
        $(".tabContents:first").show();

        $("#tabContainer ul li a").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var activeTab = $(this).attr("href");
            $("#tabContainer ul li a").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(".tabContents").hide();
            $(activeTab).fadeIn();
        });

    });
```

But when I put it in the php file like so

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($){

        $(".tabContents").hide();
        $(".tabContents:first").show();

        $("#tabContainer ul li a").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var activeTab = $(this).attr("href");
            $("#tabContainer ul li a").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(".tabContents").hide();
            $(activeTab).fadeIn();
        });

    });
</script>
```

Every thing works fine. How can I alter the code to get it to work in an exteral file vs putting in the php file? Note the exteranl files are joined, minified and compress. I also tried without joined, minified and compress. The Jquery version is 1.6

Comment: what do you mean by "does no work"? we can't read your mind.

Comment: Try adding a semicolon at the start, right before jQuery, like so: `;jQuery(function($) { ...`

Answer (score 0):

What file are you saving your jQuery into? You want to do something like this:

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Your Body Code-->
    </body>
</html>
```

myscript.js

```
jQuery(function ($){

    $(".tabContents").hide();
    $(".tabContents:first").show();

    $("#tabContainer ul li a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var activeTab = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#tabContainer ul li a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".tabContents").hide();
        $(activeTab).fadeIn();
    });

});
```

Comment: I have the file linked and the jquery.min.js linked as well. I figured that the code may be generic and conflicting with other code. The code works perfect and doesn't conflict with anything if I put it directly in the index.html file but it does when I linked to it external.